# laravel | admin only button

Tags: php, laravel, view

I'm here with a little difficulty putting a rule in which a button is only visible to users whose level is "administrator".

```
     <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{{ route('utilizadores.index') }}" class="nav-link">
      <i class="nav-icon far fa-user"></i>
      <p>
        Registo Utilizador
      </p>
    </a>
  </li>
```

I try this:

```
<?php
      if ($level_user == 'admin'){

  echo '<li class="nav-item">'
 echo   '<a href="{{ route('utilizadores.index') }}" class="nav-link">'
 echo     '<i class="nav-icon far fa-user"></i>'
 echo       '<p>'
 echo        'Regist User'
 echo       '</p>'
 echo   '</a>'
 echo '</li>'

      }
```

but exist error here:

```
 echo   '<a href="{{ route('utilizadores.index') }}" class="nav-link">'
```

Comment: how do you set $level_user

Answer (score 0):

in writing Laravel
Blade Templates
[Blade Templates](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#if-statements)

```
@if ($level_user == 'admin')
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{ route('utilizadores.index') }}" class="nav-link">
            <i class="nav-icon far fa-user"></i>
            <p>
                Registo Utilizador
            </p>
        </a>
    </li>
@endif
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).